How to find a particular line in command output?
I'm trying to find TeamIdentifier of an app. grep seemed to be the command to use but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?
codesign -dv --verbose=4 /Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ Secure\ Client\ -\ Socket\ Filter.app/ |grep TeamIdentifier

Where as for example for
ifconfig |grep 192.168

it works as expected.

For reasons known only to Apple, codesign(1) prints its output to standard error, not standard output as anyone would expect. So you have to redirect:
codesign -dv --verbose=4 /Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ Secure\ Client\ -\ Socket\ Filter.app/ 2>&1 | grep TeamIdentifier


Nice thanks! Just a pun but they also call their technical support service "Genius Bar" and I don't see any of those two things being there when I go there for help :)
Is there any way to see whether an output is standard error or standard output?

One way is to do what you just did. A pipe only transmits stdout, so if you don’t get anything from it, the output must be going to stderr. It’s pretty rare, and against convention, for normal output to be handled as if it were an error.

I see. Thanks again
